# How to create divs for slideshow image change left/ right on click?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a div that is 50% width left and another 50% width right of the viewport. I want each div to change the slideshow image previous / next on click

Example: https://jonoverrall.com/colin/owzib05x14nq1xd08etgqoe7nmmvum

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">

    <img src="001%20(1).jpg" onclick="plusSlides(1)">
    <div class="text">As a Fountain 2017</div>
    <div class="opacity">001 </div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">

    <img src="001%20(2).jpg" onclick="plusSlides(1)">
    <div class="text">Deliverance 2017</div>
    <div class="opacity">002 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vh;
  object-fit: contain;
}


.mySlides img {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }

.slideshow-container img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

JS

```
var slideIndex = 1;
var indexes = document.querySelectorAll(".numbertext span");
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
indexes[1].innerHTML = slides.length;

showSlides(slideIndex);


function plusSlides(n) {
   showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
   var i;
if (n > slides.length) {
   slideIndex = 1
}
if (n < 1) {
  slideIndex = slides.length
}
indexes[0].innerHTML = slideIndex;
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xobQRM